Detecting the number of fuzz runs in a foundry test?
Context
After having written a library that detects potential false-positives by counting how often each random test case is hit, I would like to assert, within each fuzz test function, that the manually defined test cases are reached often enough.
To determine how many fuzz runs are performed, and get that information into the tested fuzz function, I can read how many fuzz = { runs = 1_000 } are specified from the foundry.toml using something like vm.readFile or vm.parseToml():
[profile.default]
  auto_detect_solc = false
  block_timestamp = 1_680_220_800 # March 31, 2023 at 00:00 GMT
  bytecode_hash = "none"
  evm_version = "paris"           # See https://www.evmdiff.com/features?name=PUSH0&kind=opcode
  fuzz = { runs = 1_000 }
  gas_reports = ["*"]

and parse and use that total fuzz run count to assert at the end of the fuzz runs, inside each tested fuzz function, that each required test case count is sufficient.
However, that does not detect manual overrides of that command like:
forge test -vvvvvvv --fuzz-runs 99 --match-test testFuzzCaseLogging

Hence, I was wondering:
Question
Is there another way to get the number of fuzz runs, in the tested function, that is actually used in the fuzz run (also in case it is overridden with the CLI) from e.g. the environment variables?

I think, in order to achieve this, you could potentially use the afterInvariant function of the Invariant Testing, that I'd answered to the question that you asked a while ago.

When you run the fuzz test, it logs some values for each test:
(runs: 257, μ: 19213, ~: 19631)
runs refers to the number of scenarios the fuzzer tested.
https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/fuzz-testing#interpreting-results

Dear Zartaj, thank you for your suggestion, I updated the question as I did not clearly convey that I am aiming to obtain the number of fuzz runs within the tested fuzz function. Would you be willing to explain whether you also meant that that log allows the tested fuzz function to determine how many fuzz runs will be performed in total?
